# Blowup extends a regular map to $\mathbb{P}^{N+1}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, schemes, blowup

Let $(X_0,X_1,...,X_n)$ homogeneous coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^n$ and let assume that
$X^r \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is a complex variety where
$x:= (1,0,...,0) \in X$ and $X$ isn't a cone with vertex $x$.

Consider the graded ring homomorphism

$$ \phi: \mathbb{C}[X_0,...,X_n] \to \oplus_{k=0} O_{x, \mathbb{P}^n} \cdot X_0^k  $$

given by $\phi(f):= (f/X_0^k) \cdot X_0^k$ if $f$ is homogeneous of degree $k$.
It induced the graded homomorphism

$$ \psi:R_X= \mathbb{C}[X_0,...,X_n]/I(X) \to \oplus_{k=0} O_{x, X} \cdot X_0^k  $$

Define as $R^0_X := \psi^{-1}[\oplus_{k=0} m^k_{x, X} \cdot X_0^k]$
where $m_{x, X} $ is the unique maximal ideal of the local ring $\subset O_{x,X}$.

Let $f \in R^0_X$ be homogeneous of degree $l$. Consider the *embedding*
of $X-\{x\}$ into $\mathbb{P}^{N+1}$ defined by *monomials* in
$X_1,..., X_n$ of degree $l$ and $f$. Less formally the map is given by

$$ y \mapsto (X_1^l(x): ... :X_0^{l_0} \cdot X_1^{l_1} ... \cdot X_n^{l_n}(y):
...: f(y)) $$

with $\sum_i l_i =l$. Restricted to $X-\{x\}$ this map is regular.

Now let $B_x(X)$ be the blowup of $X$ in $x$. Geometrically $B_x(X)$
arise also as the Zariski closure of the graph $\Gamma_x^X
= \{(y, p_x(y)) \ \vert \ y \in X-\{x\} \} \subset \mathbb{P}^n 
\times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ where the graph $\Gamma_x^X$ is associated
to restriction of the projection from $x$ map
$p_x: \mathbb{P}^{n} \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}, (x_0:x_1:...:x_n) \mapsto
(x_1:...:x_n)$ to $X-\{x\}$.

Question: why the regular (regular means here well defined in projective sense)
embedding map $e: X-\{x\} \to \mathbb{P}^{N+1}$ from above extends
to a regular map from $B_x(X)$ to $\mathbb{P}^{N+1}$?

Source: David Mumford's Algebraic Geometry 1: Complex projective varieties.
to avoid the clumsiness of having misread something below I attatched to
original source:

[image]

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted, I think it's a good question!

Comment: I think that's a paltry way to wordless downvote questions without giving the OP any chance to improve deficiencies. It helps nobody and it requires not much time to left a short feedback what can be done better for everybody having little expertise in the 10-finger typing system

Comment: You have $N,n$. Can you clarify that?

Comment: the $n$ is the dimension of the fixed projective space where $X$ is initially embedded as closed projective subvariety. $N$ is the dimension of the $C$-vector space of monomials $X_1, ..., X_n$ of degree $ l $. Is the way how these monomials and $f$ define the embedding of $X-\{x\}$ into $\mathbb{P}^{N+1}$ clear so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attept to solve my problem, is it ok?

The blowup $B_x(X)$ of $X$ in $x $ equals (? or is at least included in
the set

$$ \{([x_0: x_1: ... x_n], [y_1:... y_n]) \ \vert \ x \in X, 
x_i y_j - x_j y_i \} \subset  \mathbb{P}^n 
\times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}      $$

We have $X_0, X_1,..., X_n$ as coordinate functions of left factor
$\mathbb{P}^n$ and $Y_1,..., Y_n$ as cofu of right factor $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$.

Now it looks reasonable for me to extend the map
$X-\{x\} \to \mathbb{P}^{N+1}$ given by

$$y \mapsto (X_1^l(x): ... :X_0^{l_0} \cdot X_1^{l_1} ... \cdot X_n^{l_n}(y):
...: f(y))$$

by replacing all $X_i$ with $0<i \ge n$ by $Y_i$. This looks like an
extension of map from $X-\{x\}$ above because by definition for
every $[x_0: x_1: ... x_n] \in X -  \{[1:0:...:0]\}$ there is inique
$[y_1: ... y_n] \in \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ with
$([x_0: x_1: ... x_n], [y_1:... y_n]) \in B_x(X)$ and
it is also welldefined in $\{ x \} \times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$.

Is the 'solution' acceptable? Unsolved question:
is the set
$ \{([x_0: x_1: ... x_n], [y_1:... y_n]) \ \vert \ x \in X, 
x_i y_j - x_j y_i \} \subset  \mathbb{P}^n 
\times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}      $ equal to the blowup $B_x(X)$ of $X$ in $x$
or does it only contain $B_x(X)$ properly? More precisely
does the fiber of natural map $B_x(X) \to X$ or equal to
$\{ x \} \times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$?